# changing the current set locale on a Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, locale

I have a Ubuntu system on which current locale is(output of locale command):

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I want to change it to en_GB, because some characters are not handled properly on the terminal display.

What is the command to change the locale?

What is the command to see what different locales are available on current system for me to set/try?

Comment: IMO, switching away from UTF-8 is *never* a solution. I've had my last name mangled one time too many.

Comment: What terminal are you using? most of the X11 terminal emulators support utf-8, and utf-8 is the new unix standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The used locale is set via environment variables for the process (like the shell running in your terminal).

Most of the time it is sufficient to just change `LANG`, assuming you use `bash`

```
$ export LANG=en_GB
```

Put this into your `~/.profile` file to make it work for all (even non-terminal) processes.

You can have a look at `/usr/share/locale/` for some list of locales.

Comment: Thanks. But when I was trying to set my locale to POSIX, but could not see any entry like 'POSIX' in /usr/share/locale file.

Comment: Try `C` for LANG.

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `locale -a` to get a list of available locales on your system (in addition to `/usr/share/locale/`, there may be some found in  `/usr/lib/locale/`. For setting the locale, there's also the command `setlocale`, but I never got that to work and used `export` as the user *honk* described.